# Initializing jquery plugins in angularjs directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, but I went through a lot of angular 2-way binding posts and frankly couldn't understand what they were talking about. So I'll just state my problem again.

Lets say I want to use a tags input plugin such as [this](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html). I define an angular directive called tags and within it, initialize tagsinput on a text input. The text element is bound to a model which is populated in the controller from a service.

I have this in Plunker [here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hIvJjq)

The problem is when the directive loads, the model is not populated yet, so the tagsinput plugin is initialized with an empty value. But I want it to be initialized with a server side value. I've come across this problem often and I've been resorting to initializing my plugins in service callbacks within controllers which I know is cardinal sin.

I'm unable to get out of thinking that eventually, at some level, the plugin initialization must be delayed until the service returns so the value is available. And am I correct if I say that even in the angular way of doing it, this is somehow achieved? But in any case, I'm not able to figure out how to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to solve this problem is using a watcher inside your directive.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', function ($scope, $timeout) {

   //this simulates data being loaded asynchronously after 3 second 
   $timeout(function () {
       $scope.list = [1, 2, 3, 4];
   }, 3000);

});

app.directive("mydirective", function()
{   
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.$watch('list', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal) {

                    //initialize the plugns etc
                    scope.result = 'Model has been populated';
                }    
            });
        }
    };
});
```

In my example I am using $timeout inside the controller to simulate an async load of data, once the 'list' model gets populated the watcher inside the directive will realize it (newVal is not empty or undefined) and then the plugin can be initialized. This is a better approach instead of callbacks inside the controller because your code is much more concise.

Here is a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/iwewub/15/edit)

EDIT:

Just remember that the digest cycle has to be fired when the model is populated. If you are using $resource or $http to fetch the data from the server you don't have to worry, but if you are doing it outside Angular you will have to fire the digest cycle with $scope.$apply() so the watcher can be aware that the model was populated.

Answer (score 1):

As Bertrand said it's achievable by using watchers in directives `link` function. You need to wait for data to appear and this is what watchers are for. Take a look at my update to your plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/hb3UYl.

I faked async response with `$timeout` instead of `$http` but it doesn't really matter here.

What it does is it sets up watcher in directive's link function which looks for changes of `$scope.list`. If change is detected and `newValue` is something useful it uses it to populate input field and turn it into tag list.

Notice I changed your `$('.taginput')` into `element` as this is what you are operating on. Also I think this is good practice to search for DOM elements you want to manipulate only down the hierarchy of current `element`. This makes you sure that if you place directive on given element - no other elements except this one and its children will be impacted.